# How to get to know if one textbox overlaps other textbox in excel

Tags: c#, .net, excel, textbox

There are many textboxes in a excel and I need to find which textbox overlaps a specific textbox or which is the nearest overlapping textbox[image]

Please refer the image for more clarification. Ex: in the above image I need to find textbox containing number "2" is overlapped by which textbox and which is nearest one.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get position of textbox by using Left, right, height and width properties
2. Map the properties as shown below to verify whether one textbox overlaps other.
3. Overlap can be checked by two ways horizontal and vertical overlap. If in both case it is overlapped then it is considered as overlapped.
4. For exact overlaps values of both textboxes should be same. Can checks equals

Code -

```
var shapeTextBox1 = sheet.TextBoxes1 as XlsTextBoxShape;
var shapeLeft = shapeTextBox1.Left;
var shapeRight = shapeTextBox1.Left + shapeTextBox1.Width;
var shapeTop = shapeTextBox1.Top;
var shapeBottom = shapeTextBox1.Top + shapeTextBox1.Height;
var looped = sheet.TextBoxes2 as XlsTextBoxShape;
var secondShapeLeft = looped.Left;
var secondShapeRight = looped.Left + looped.Width;
var secondShapeTop = looped.Top;
var secondShapeBottom = looped.Top + looped.Height;
//horizontal overlap
if(shapeLeft>secondShapeLeft)
{
    if(shapeLeft<secondShapeRight)
    {bHorizontalOverlap=true;}
    }
if (shapeLeft < secondShapeLeft)
{
    if (shapeRight > secondShapeLeft)
    {bHorizontalOverlap = true;}
}
//vertical overlap
if(shapeTop>secondShapeTop)
{
    if(shapeTop<secondShapeBottom)
    { bVerticalOverlap = true; }
}
if(shapeTop < secondShapeTop)
{
    if(shapeBottom > secondShapeTop)
    { bVerticalOverlap = true; }
}
ShapesOverlap = bHorizontalOverlap && bVerticalOverlap;
if(ShapesOverlap)
{
    //further logic as required
}
```